# How to run a method with Task.WhenAll for every item in list and store the results?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm working on an application that retrieves RSS feeds every few minutes and downloads the items on the feeds matching a set of criterias. However, I'm struggling to debug the code below. When I set up breakpoints in my code, it doesn't go past the first line in `GoThroughFeeds()`. I suspect that there is something wrong with the way I create and handle tasks. Initially, I created the tasks using `Task.Run()`, but they would run twice (the second batch after the await). What am I doing wrong?

```
private async void RunOnInterval(TimeSpan delay)
{
  do
  {
    await GoThroughFeeds();
    await Task.Delay(delay);

  } while (true);
}

private async Task GoThroughFeeds()
{
  Feed[] updatedFeeds = await Task
    .WhenAll(Repository.Data.Feeds.Select(feed => new Task<Feed>(() => FetchRss(feed))));

  // Do more stuff with the feeds
}

public Feed FetchRss(Feed feed)
{
  feed.Items = Repository.GetItems(feed);
  return feed;
}
```

Comment: `new Task<Feed>(() => FetchRss(feed))` is definitely wrong. You're waiting for a task that is never started. I don't really understand why you had trouble with `Task.Run`

Comment: When I changed from `new Task(() => FetchRss(feed)))` to `Task.FromResult(FetchRss(feed))`, it started to work. `Task.Run()` wouldn't work in this scenario, because I need the return value and it only takes `Action. There was probably something else wrong with my code earlier, that led me to believe I needed to use `new Task` instead of the static methods on `Task`, because I thought they would immediately run.

Comment: `Task.FromResult` will execute the function synchronously, so that's not what you want. You can use `Task.Run` with a `Func`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're right. When I used Task.Run, the updating went considerably faster. If you want to write it down as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Task<Feed>(() => FetchRss(feed))` is wrong. You're trying to wait on a task that isn't started. In fact, the constructor of Task should almost never be used.

`Task.FromResult` isn't good either, as it'll execute your code synchronously, instead of offloading it to a different thread.

In the end, `Task.Run` does exactly what you need.